# Write text to .bat file at specified position in Java

Tags: java

I have a requirement to edit the `.bat` file with Java.

The file contains following line of text

```
testrunner.bat -ParId=12810 -PsysDate=2014-07-03 "C:\SOAP METHODS\DELINQ-soapui-project.xml"
```

Here I have a string `-ParId=12810` and `-PsysDate=2014-07-03`, in this I need to write the new content after `=` sign, i.e. I need to assign different values to `-ParId` and `-PsysDate` variables.

Comment: Show us your Java code.

Comment: Is the text without the parameters always the same or may it change?

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with rewriting the complete file?

Comment: This is not at all an answer. Please comment for such things.

Comment: He coudln't due to new user restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about regex, in fact i almost never used it, but you can utilizing regex for your problem, something like:

```
class RegexExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "testrunner.bat -ParId=12810 -PsysDate=2014-07-03 'C:\\SOAP METHODS\\DELINQ-soapui-project.xml'";
        input = input.replaceAll("ParId=[0-9]+","ParId=newValueID");
        input = input.replaceAll("PsysDate=\\w+\\-\\w+\\-\\w+","PsysDate=newValueDate");
        System.out.println(input);
    }
}
```

I know it is not the most efficient or pretty, but you can start from there, many references found in Google though :)

Answer (score 0):

If the file always contains the same text(without the parameters) you could do:

```
String formatstr = "testrunner.bat -ParId=%d -PsysDate=%s \"C:\SOAP METHODS\DELINQ-soapui-project.xml\"";
String output = String.format(formatstr,id,datestring);
// write output to file
```